# Is it possible to make a gradient color of a stroke that composes a SVG image

Tags: css, svg, sass

I would like to know if is it possible to do a gradient in the stroke color that appears in the two lines below, and is set to #389967. This is a SVG

```
.chart-three svg .circle-foreground {

  stroke: #389967;
  stroke-dasharray: 494.55px 549.5px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 494.55px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
          transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

THe full source code can be found here, it's on scss, but you can compile it to CSS :

https://codepen.io/kunalkamble/pen/XXbWwN

I'm looking to change the foreground color of this chart, in order to get it gradient, do you know if that is possible ?

I would like to measure like a meter of energy consumption, when is very close to 0% is green and when it gets close to 100% is red

thanks in advance

Comment: Your codepen is bugging out and stuck in a reload loop - not sure if the site is just having a problem or it's something in your code!

Comment: I have updated the link, could you please try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable using an image stored as an SVG pattern for your stroke, with the caveat being that you can no longer round the edges. The stroke caps technically go past the start of your element, so a sliver of the 100% value of the gradient (red) peeks in unless you remove it.

https://codepen.io/will0220/pen/xXjKry

```
<svg role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="fillColors" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200" height="200">
      <image xlink:href="http://willmurdoch.com/images/strokeGrad.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </pattern>
    <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Then use that as the foreground color. If you plan on using the same image I did, please save it down from the link above and re-upload it somewhere else, since it's hosted on my personal server.